# ResourceDictionary and Styles not merging across application

Tags: wpf, styles, resourcedictionary

I have an application that uses a ResourceDictionary  to set the styles, which it does nicely. However, the font is a little small and I would like to change that but the resource directory is from a .dll so I can't edit it.

As you will notice I'm just starting out with dictionaries.

I thought I could override this by using MergedDictionaries and just add a style to override it:

```
<Application x:Class="IDIUserInterface.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="Windows/WindowMain.xaml" >
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="/ReuxablesLegacy;component/mercury.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Page">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

To my shock this actually worked, but only in the design view. As soon as I compiled the code and ran the application the fonts return to their former size.

Is there a reason for this or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,
SumGuy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone interested I solved it with:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="/ReuxablesLegacy;component/mercury.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary>

                <Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="MyPageStyle" TargetType="Page">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

And then added

```
Style="{StaticResource MyWindowStyle}"
```

...into the window header (or substitute Page for pages)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
<Style TargetType="Page">
```

To

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't solve it. Is there anything I would need to add to the Window or Page header to activate this?

Comment: What are you exactly try to achieve?

Comment: Simple really. I just want to override the resource directory that contains the styles (It's from a .dll so I can't change directly). So that instead of using say, the fontsize, from the resource directory it uses the one I specify.
I can do it within the Window/Page init but that would mean changing each and every one.

Comment: But The problem here is your changing the Window/Page font size. All your controls will override this if you set it there